# Fluid domain dimensions are different in Edit mode from Object mode

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am building a beach scene and have a strange thing happening to my domain. Basically the domain dimensions are different when I switch to edit mode. I think I scaled the cube once it was a domain, I'm not sure if that was the cause. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

[image: Object Mode Left - Edit Mode Right]

Comment: This could be the simulated fluid, have you tried turning off the simulation? Are there any (1) shapekeys (2) modifiers [displace/deform] (3) active scripts? Have you tried to apply the scale to the domain object?

Comment: Yes, the photo is the view of the domain with the simulation off (eyeball deselected). There are no shape keys in this project and all objects have applied scales so they are all 1:1:1. There are no scripts used. I was following the CG Geek's YouTube Tutorial on Beach Waves and ran into this so I'm not sure where I went astray. The simulation still bakes correctly I think, but the fluid was going in places I wasn't expecting it to and that's when I noticed this weird thing going on.